# The structure of the electron as a particle

Tags: electrons, elementary-particles

has anyone found the minimum radius of the electron including the magnetic field ( dipole moment) ? The 'classsical' radius only uses the electric field, and so is a minimum radius for a purely electric electron, but the magnetic field has been ignored.

Comment: As I remember, it did not make sense: rotational surface velocities larger than lightspeed would be required to produce the magnetic moment.

Comment: The magnetic moment exists independently of any theoretical model, it physically exists.  The question is intended to be a complimentary computation to the 'classcal' electron radius. Your comment seems to be concerned with classical models of electron structure...

Comment: I misspoke - The question involves a calculation using the actual magnetic field ( moment ) and the actual electric field. Ths is not a 'structure' question. It is a physical minimum radius based on the actual fields, observed from physical interactions with electrons, based on energy. The minimum radius obtained from ths calculation will be more valid than any other possible radius from theory, since the theories all disagree and give impossbly small radii...

Comment: [There](https://www.academia.edu/18391675/About_the_distribution_of_electrons_magnetic_dipole_moments_in_atoms_Part_1) is a calculation of mine about would it be consistent if to take as a basis the covalent radii. Looks good.

Comment: Sorry, Mr. HolgerFiedler, the paper you pointed to concerns bound electrons and covalent bonds. I have the book on molecular quantum electrodynamics by Thirunamachandran, and it is more in-depth. I am concerned with the actual external electromagnetic fields of the electron and the physical values obtainable from them external to any structure of the electron, whether it is a point or not, whether the theory is QED, QFT or QCD or not.